# How to encode/decode pojo objects in Netty?

Tags: netty

How to encode/decode pojo objects in Netty ? Any default encoder decoder can do this efficiently (can easily add/modify pojo without the need to change encode/decode method)? Example would the most appreciated.

Comment: Why don't use standard serialization ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

Netty provides [ObjectEncoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectEncoder.html) and ObjectDecoder which can be used code and decode POJOs using java serialization mechanism.

Have a look on the example:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/objectecho